# what's the effect on running jvm instance when upgrading jdk version

Tags: java

The following exception happened after I upgraded jre version from `1.8.0_121` to `1.8.0_131`:

```
DocumentException: Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.SAXMessages Nested exception: Could not load any resource bundle by com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.msg.SAXMessages
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
        at org.dom4j.DocumentHelper.parseText(DocumentHelper.java:278)
        at
```

after restarting jvm instance, the `exception` disappeared.
I guess it was related with library files, but I can not prove it.
So what's the sound explanation?

Comment: If you deleted your jre 1.8.0_121 while the jvm was running on it, you might have lost files the jvm needed. A jvm restart is necessary for the jvm to run on the new jre.

Comment: I'd say "undefined" at least in the broader sense. Don't do that.